# Splitting a complex object to two separated key and value collections

Tags: c#, serialization, recursion

I'm trying to implement the C# aspect of a LightWeight JSON Spec [JsonR](https://github.com/itechnology/JsonRaw), but cannot get my head around any kind of recursion :-/ If anyone could help out here it would be more than greatly appreciated.

```
// Mockup class
public class User {
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    public int Age     { get; set; }
    public List<string> Photos  { get; set; }
    public List<Friend> Friends { get; set; }       
}

// Mockup class
public class Friend {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName  { get; set; }
}

// Initialize objects
var userList = new List<User>();
userList.Add(new User() { 
    Name   = "Robert",
    Age     = 32,
    Photos  = new List<string> { "1.jpg", "2.jpg" },
    Friends = new List<Friend>() {
        new Friend() { FirstName = "Bob", LastName = "Hope"},
        new Friend() { FirstName = "Mr" , LastName = "T"}
    }
}); 
userList.Add(new User() { 
    Name   = "Jane",
    Age     = 21,
    Photos  = new List<string> { "4.jpg", "5.jpg" },
    Friends = new List<Friend>() {
        new Friend() { FirstName = "Foo"  , LastName = "Bar"},
        new Friend() { FirstName = "Lady" , LastName = "Gaga"}
    }
});
```

The idea behind it all is to now take the above object and split it into 2 separate collections, one containing the keys, and the other containing the values. Like this we can eventually only send the values over the wire thus saving lots of bandwidth, and then recombine it on the client (a js implementation for recombining exists already)

If all went well we should be able to get this out of the above object

```
var keys   = new object[] {
    "Name", "Age", "Photos",
    new { Friends = new [] {"FirstName", "LastName"}}};
var values = new [] {
    new object[] {"Robert", 32, new [] {"1.jpg", "2.jpg"},
                                new [] { new [] {"Bob", "Hope"},
                                         new [] {"Mr", "T"}}},
    new object[] {"Jane", 21, new [] {"4.jpg", "5.jpg"},
                              new [] { new [] {"Foo", "Bar"},
                                       new [] {"Lady", "Gaga"}}}};
```

As a verification we can test the conformity of the result with

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(keys).Dump("keys");
// Generates:
// ["Name","Age","Photos",{"Friends":["FirstName","LastName"]}]

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values).Dump("values");
// Generates:
// [["Robert",32,["1.jpg","2.jpg"],[["Bob","Hope"],["Mr","T"]]],["Jane",21,["4.jpg","5.jpg"],[["Foo","Bar"],["Lady","Gaga"]]]]
```

A shortcut i explored was to take advantage of Newton's JArray/JObject facilities like this

```
var JResult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userList));
```

Like this we end up with a sort of array object that we can already start iterating on

Anyone think they can crack this in a memory/speed efficient way ?

Comment: Of course if someone can crack this you'll get full credits for it in the JsonR project. Heck, I'll even give up half of my reputation points, or donate to your beerfund if that's what it takes :)

Comment: Did you rule out Reflection? It's not exactly speedy but it will provide a way to handle whatever data structure you throw at it.

Comment: @dutzu no i didn't rule anything out at all, however we can be dealing with millions of requests/day depending on who uses it, since it's destined to be the serializer part on the webserver's end. That's one reason i thought of the JObject/JArray shortcut, since NewtonSoft will already take some pretty heavy lifting out of it, ..if going that path. But i might be wrong..

Comment: Do you want a generic object serialiser? How should the elements be ordered?

Comment: @Robert I'm working on a solution (purely for my own exercise). You *have* to use reflection there's no other way around it, however you can cache the dynamic serializers around the known types. So once you've used it once, next time there is no reflection, just pulling the de-serializer out of cache.

Comment: @Jodrell The final order does not really matter. Whats important is that keys and values are ordered in the same way. Yes only public members. The behavior should be the same as the .NET JavaScriptSerializer, except that it's splitting keys/values into 2 distinct collections. The final result will have a JavascriptSerializer called on it anyways, since in the end we are returning a sort of JSON light.

Comment: recursion (circular references) are the gotcha.

Comment: @StanR. Sounds like a good tradeoff between flexibility and performance. But i kind of wonder if since we will be calling a JavaScript serializer on the final result anyways, if this couldn't be achieved with some fancy regex to just reformat the final result. But don't let that stop you ..just tossing ideas

Comment: @Stan R., its a interesting idea, at the same time as reflecting the `"keys"` or schema you could build an expression for deserialising the `"values"` which you could then compile for later use.

Comment: The example of the generated result (from Newton) for values was the wrong example, updated the above code. sorry !

Comment: @Jodrell I took the idea from Dapper NET. obviously you can reflect against public properties and public properties of nested types and create a string array of that. Then using reflection get their "get" methods for the `values`. However the problem is in creating the anonymous types for those nested types.

Comment: the idea is to create a dynamic method that creates the correct output given one type. then cache the dynamic method for that type. for instance have you thought what happens if `Friend` class another nested class inside..it just keeps doing recursive dynamic methods for that type.

Comment: @Robert going to have to wait until i get home, can't work on this @ work :(

Comment: @StanR. Nothing pressing here. Really appreciate the help !

Comment: @StanR. If you have LinqPad, try this. Add a reference to NewtonSoft and try the serialize/deserialize trick. You end up with a json compatible object that consists solely of very simple objects/arrays that only contain JSON primitives. Anything public/private, classes, etc, completely disappears. I'm pretty sure that from there it's possible to efficiently iterate over the result to construct the desired output. ..again just tossing ideas :) Me too i'm getting off work now and will go setup some demo pages on github

Comment: @StanR. Hope i didn't scare you off with my repeated talk about Newton ! Definitely curious to see your cached expression version

Comment: @Robert no, i looked at the Newton result yesterday, it's close to what you want...but it doesn't really get you there. It also seems like a real PITA to navigate those results. I'm still thinking of an implementation.

Comment: @StanR. Great to hear. After posting yesterday i thought that probably anyways serializing, then deserializing, then iterating/building and again reserializing. ..well i'm sure reflection + some cache will be just as fast ! :)

Comment: @StanR. Just thought of something maybe important. You said earlier that the real problem is "creating the anonymous types". They don't have to be anonymous. They could just as well be a List<object> or whatever serializes to the same result. Or it could output a string directly without passing by any type of object. In the end this will be returning a simple string anyways, whether directly or via calling a ToJson() on some js serializer.

Comment: so i dont need something like `new { Friends = new [] {"FirstName", "LastName"}}` i can just simply do `new [] {"FirstName", "LastName"}`

Comment: @StanR. Well, the final result will still have to resolve to {"Friends":["FirstName","LastName"]} for things to work right (this is in JSON notation of course). But whether one gets there with new [] {}, List<object>, or by directly concatenating the string, doesn't really matter is what i meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a solution that works with your example data. It is not a universal solution and may fail with other examples, but it shows how to use recursions. I did not include any error handling. A real-world solution would have to.

I use this helper method which gets the item type of the generic lists:

```
private static Type GetListItemType(Type listType)
{
    Type itemType = null;
    foreach (Type interfaceType in listType.GetInterfaces()) {
        if (interfaceType.IsGenericType &&
            interfaceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>)) {
            itemType = interfaceType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            break;
        }
    }
    return itemType;
}
```

Now, the recursion:

```
public void SplitKeyValues(IList source, List<object> keys, List<object> values)
{
    Type itemType = GetListItemType(source.GetType());
    PropertyInfo[] properties = itemType.GetProperties();
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Count; i++) {
        object item = source[i];
        var itemValues = new List<object>();
        values.Add(itemValues);
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in properties) {
            if (typeof(IList).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType) &&
                prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType) {
                // We have a List<T> or array

                Type genericArgType = GetListItemType(prop.PropertyType);
                if (genericArgType.IsValueType || genericArgType == typeof(string)) {
                    // We have a list or array of a simple type
                    if (i == 0)
                        keys.Add(prop.Name);
                    List<object> subValues = new List<object>();
                    itemValues.Add(subValues);
                    subValues.AddRange(
                        Enumerable.Cast<object>(
                            (IEnumerable)prop.GetValue(item, null)));
                } else {
                    // We have a list or array of a complex type
                    List<object> subKeys = new List<object>();
                    if (i == 0)
                        keys.Add(subKeys);
                    List<object> subValues = new List<object>();
                    itemValues.Add(subValues);
                    SplitKeyValues(
                        (IList)prop.GetValue(item, null), subKeys, subValues);
                }
            } else if (prop.PropertyType.IsValueType ||
                       prop.PropertyType == typeof(string)) {
                // We have a simple type
                if (i == 0)
                    keys.Add(prop.Name);
                itemValues.Add(prop.GetValue(item, null));
            } else {
                // We have a complex type.
                // Does not occur in your example
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I call it like this:

```
List<User> userList = InitializeObjects();
List<object> keys = new List<object>();
List<object> values = new List<object>();
SplitKeyValues(userList, keys, values);
```

`InitializeObjects` initializes the user list as you did above.

---

**UPDATE**

The problem is that you are using an anonymous type `new { Friends = ... }`. You would have to create an anonymous type dynamically by using reflection. And that's pretty nasty. The article ["Extend Anonymous Types using Reflection.Emit"](http://www.developmentalmadness.com/archive/2008/02/12/extend-anonymous-types-using.aspx) seems to do it. (I didn't test it).

Maybe an easier approach would do the job. I suggest creating a helper class for the description of class types.

```
public class Class
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<object> Structure { get; set; }
}
```

Now let's replace an else case in the code above:

```
...
} else {
    // We have a list or array of a complex type
    List<object> subKeys = new List<object>();
    var classDescr = new Class { Name = genericArgType.Name, Structure = subKeys };
    if (i == 0)
        keys.Add(classDescr);
    List<object> subValues = new List<object>();
    itemValues.Add(subValues);
    SplitKeyValues(
        (IList)prop.GetValue(item, null), subKeys, subValues);
}
...
```

The result is:
[image]

Comment: I'm don't have access to a real pc right now, but once i get back home I'll be sure to give this a try, tnx!

Comment: Got back home and gave your code a try ..pretty sweet ! The values generated are perfect, unfortunately the keys loose the friends object. Generated: ``["Name","Age","Photos",["FirstName","LastName"]]``  Expected: ``["Name","Age","Photos",{"Friends":["FirstName","LastName"]}]``. Do you think this can be achieved with your code, or is it always just arrays ? I'm gonna play a bit with it, but reflection & recursion are a bit beyond me. In any case this looks the most promising so far

Comment: I guess the user object could also be expressed as ``{User: ["Name","Age","Photos", {"Friends": ["FirstName","LastName"]}]}`` if that makes more sense. However in the end we will be returning ``{Type: "User", Keys: ["Name","Age","Photos", {"Friends": ["FirstName","LastName"]}], Values: [....]}`` Actually it will either be keys/values, or type/values (with keys stored in a look-up dictionary on the client), never all three.

Comment: Haven't tried your updated example, but i currently am able to make things work by replacing ``keys.Add(subKeys)`` inside ``// We have a list or array of a complex type`` with ``keys.Add(new Dictionary<string, object>(1) {{prop.Name, subKeys}})``. This seems to do the trick. I'll investigate your updated example though, unless you think my tweak is good enough ..i'm just doing a bunch of trial/error, not even 100% sure if i'm not doing nasty things here ! :)

Comment: Gonna consider this OK ! :) Now just need to wrap it all up in a nice transparent method with some error handling and helper logic to get nice JsonResults in MVC, and something similar in asp.net ..but that's the easy part. Thanks again, and if you have some extra tips or whatever, i'm all ears. ..oh and outta curiosity. What on earth where you using this for ?

Comment: I just made it for you. It's the reason why it's not an universal solution but adapted to your example.

Comment: Thank you even so more then, merci encore !

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try an external tool, like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/), which is a convention based mapping library.

I suggest to try the [flattening](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Flattening) feature with your own conventions.

I'm sorry I cannot write out an example because of lack of time, but I think the ideas behind this open source library might help a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but i think the above code from Olivier will do the trick just nicely. I really do prefer just a extra function or 2 to achieve the result, than adding supplementary dependencies. ..but if Olivier hadn't posted his solution i might have gone that route :)